# java program crash even with large -Xmx30g

Tags: java, memory

I have a large HashMap that reads from a 3GB file.  I use
java -Xmx30g (the machine has 50+GB of RAM), however it still gets killed some point time when adding element to the map, 
what would be the reason?  how do I troubleshoot this?

```
   
Map map=new HashMap();
```

Comment: 32 bit machine or 64 bit machine? maybe some other data structures eating up memory as well

Comment: Your question raises a question in my mind... why would you need to hold 3GB of data in memory (I presume outside of your app)?  I would presume that 3GB of data is not actually displayed on the screen at any given point in time, so that much data in memory isn't necessary (even for a design that is responsive to user inquiries).  And... if you need to loan that 50+GB machine out, I'll borrow it... I am at a measly 12GB, lol.

Comment: Examine the javacore dump to find out what you're spending the memory space on. Consider whether you really intended to keep all of that in memory at once. If so, think about whether there's a better way to represent it... or if you ought to reorganize the problem to handle it in smaller chunks. If not, figure out what's still referring to it and keeping it from being garbage collected.

Comment: If you are using Linux, read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

Comment: If the VM does not like the memory param it will tell you on startup. Did you verify in the console that it took it?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure about the data you are reading from file a storing to HashMap, so my answer can not be concrete and specific.

But consider this things:

1. Characters in java strings are unicode and consume 2 bytes. So if your file contains strings their size in memory can be double (about 6GB).
2. HashMap structure has its own memory occupation
3. Java split heap memory in more spaces: youg gen, old gen, perm gen (http://www.pointsoftware.ch/de/under-the-hood-runtime-data-areas-javas-memory-model/) so maybe you are not able to use all the 30g that you expect to use

My first suggestion is to add a log info that count how many lines of your file you are able to insert with `-Xmx10g`, then `-Xmx20g`, then `-Xmx30g`. If this number there are not particular problem, but normal memory usage.

**Another note**: JVM and garbage collection, can have poor performance when the heap space is too large. So it is not a best practice grow the heap in that way. Try an alternative solution, like an embedded db (Java has its own: [Derby](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/), but you can find alternatives).